# Update object property in dictionary of objects?

Tags: class, object, dictionary, vbscript

I have a dictionary of objects.  Each object is an error. As I loop through the errors in the log I am adding the object to the dictionary using the description as the key.  If the key already exists, I want to update the count.  This is where I'm having trouble; updating the count.

**Definition:**

```
Class errClass
    Dim errDesc, errType, hasPhr, errCount, lwCount, errPriority, edge
End Class

Dim errs: Set errs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
```

**Population:**

```
errDetails.errDesc = resultSet("eventtext")
errDetails.errType = resultSet("eventtype")
errDetails.edge = resultSet("namespace")
errDetails.errPriority = 1

If errs.Exists(errDetails.errDesc) Then
    If dev Then WScript.Echo "Key exists, incrementing count"
    errs.Item(errDetails.errDesc)("errCount") = errs.Item(errDetails.errDesc)("errCount") + 1
Else
    If dev Then WScript.Echo "Key does not exist, adding"
    errs.Add errDetails.errDesc, errDetails
End If
```

Just above is where the error occurs: `errs.Item(errDetails.errDesc)("errCount") = errs.Item(errDetails.errDesc)("errCount") + 1`

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'errs.Item(...)'

What is the proper way to update a property of an object within a dictionary?

Comment: `errs.Item(errDetails.errDesc)("errCount")` -> `errs.Item(errDetails.errDesc).errCount`

Comment: Was writing up the answer while you commented @AnsgarWiechers, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansgar did this in the comments, but here's a sample of the code.

```
Class errClass
    Public errDesc, errType, hasPhr, errCount, lwCount, errPriority, edge
End Class

dim errDetails : set errdetails = new errClass

Dim errs: Set errs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dim dev: dev = true
errDetails.errDesc = "test"
errDetails.errType = "test"
errDetails.edge = "test"
errDetails.errPriority = 1

errs.Add errDetails.errDesc, errDetails

errs.Item(errDetails.errDesc).errCount = errs.Item(errDetails.errDesc).errCount + 100

msgbox errs.Item(errDetails.errDesc).errCount
```

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you can't use strings to refere to object properties.

But as objects are references, you dictionary needs to hold distinct instances and the count starts with 1. So:

```
Class errClass
    Dim errDesc, errCount
    Public Sub show
      WScript.Echo errDesc, errCount
    End Sub
End Class

' dictionary of errClass objects
Dim errs : Set errs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim e
For Each e In Split("stupid silly stupid")
    If errs.Exists(e) Then 
       WScript.Echo "Key exists, incrementing count"
       errs(e).errCount = errs(e).errCount + 1
    Else
       WScript.Echo "new Key, adding new object to dictionary"
       Dim o : Set o = New errClass : o.errDesc = e : o.errCount = 1
       errs.add e, o
    End If
Next

For Each e In errs.Keys()
    errs(e).show
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 41878841.vbs
new Key, adding new object to dictionary
new Key, adding new object to dictionary
Key exists, incrementing count
stupid 2
silly 1
```